# write a program to check given file exist or not

Tags: linux

**This program gives me error**

```
echo enter the file name
read fname
If [-a $fname] 
then
   echo "$num is negative"
else
   echo "cannot find a file"
```

the error is:

```
bsccs.sh: line 3: [-a: command not found
cannot find a file
```

Comment: This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or _a simple typographical error._ While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a space:

```
if [ -a $fname ]
```

Also, 'If' is invalid. It must be lowercase.